# Android ConnectivityManager can't find permission ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

Tags: android, network-programming, android-permissions

I'm trying to read some data from a SpringBoot API request. I've added permission to the AndroidManifest.xml:

< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

My code that tries to access network state:

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){

```
        Network nw = connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork();
        if (nw == null){
            return false;
        }

        NetworkCapabilities actNw = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(nw);

        return actNw != null & (actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) ||
                actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR));
    } else {
        NetworkInfo nwInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return nwInfo != null && nwInfo.isConnected();
    }
```

And the problems that make my app doesn't work:

[Android problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3Lk0.png)

Comment: Looks like you have a space between the less than sign and uses. Have you tried removing it? It's a long shot but otherwise, what you have looks correct. The only other thing I could think of is that you should confirm that you've updated the correct manifest file.

Comment: Yeah I have a space there but I just put it to show the part of the code (if I remove it the line is not shown here) In my project I have it without the space

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the permission in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Android requires access to certain components and functionality to be declared in the manifest. Some you only need to declare in order to use, such as `INTERNET` and `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`, others require various additional steps dependent on their protection level.

Comment: I know, and I have the permission declared in the AndroidManifest.xml as it should be written and the error continues to appear